# Access parent class for a Django model

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model structure along the lines of:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    STORE_TYPE = (
        ('I', 'Ice Cream'),
        ('H', 'Hardware'),
    ) 
    retailer_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STORE_TYPE)
    ...

class HardwareStore(Store):
        hammers_stocked = models.BooleanField()
```

If I have an instance of `HardwareStore`, how do I access the `Store` object. I'm currently using

```
Retailer.objects.get(pk=hardware_store.pk)
```

where `hardware_store` is an instance of `HardwareStore` but that seems clunky

Comment: I think we're missing some pieces of the puzzle to be able to help you. Please post more of your models definitions.

Comment: I had a mistake in the example, which could be where the confusion came from. Edited to fix.

Comment: You might like to know about the `dir` function, and the `._meta` field of model instances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not quite sure about relationship between `Store` and `Retailer`, can you post some code?
To access `Retailer` instance by model-inheritance, use

```
hardware_store.retailer_ptr
```